# Display/Print one column from a DataFrame of Series in Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, series

I created the following Series and DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

Series_1 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Adam','Item': 'Sweet','Cost': 1})
Series_2 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Bob','Item': 'Candy','Cost': 2})
Series_3 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Cathy','Item': 'Chocolate','Cost': 3})`
df = pd.DataFrame([Series_1,Series_2,Series_3], index=['Store 1', 'Store 2', 'Store 3'])
```

I want to display/print out just one column from the DataFrame (with or without the header row):

Either

```
Adam 
Bob 
Cathy
```

Or:

```
Sweet
Candy
Chocolate
```

I have tried the following code which did not work:

```
print(df['Item'])
print(df.loc['Store 1'])
print(df.loc['Store 1','Item'])
print(df.loc['Store 1','Name'])
print(df.loc[:,'Item'])
print(df.iloc[0])
```

Can I do it in one simple line of code?

Comment: @JohnGalt Hi, I am starting out to learn pandas and trying to grasp the usage of different functions and methods.

Comment: Are you using IPython and started with [10 Minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#min)?

Comment: @JohnGalt I am running a local session of Jupyter Notebook and following a course on Coursera

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By using [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)

```
print(df.Name.to_string(index=False))


 Adam
  Bob
Cathy
```

Comment: to_string makes more sense. Pick this answer please

Answer (score 19):

For printing the Name column

```
df['Name']
```

Answer (score 10):

Not sure what you are really after but if you want to print exactly what you have you can do:

**Option 1**

```
print(df['Item'].to_csv(index=False))

Sweet
Candy
Chocolate
```

---

**Option 2**

```
for v in df['Item']:
    print(v)

Sweet
Candy
Chocolate
```