# For loop in dataframe to print the max and min value for every city

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I **specifically wanted to use "for loop"** to print the max sales and min sales for every city but I guess I am missing something.

```
for city in df:
    print(max(df['sales']))
```

This gives me max overall sales and not max sales by city. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `city` variable?

Comment: Without seeing your df, you likely don't need a loop at all. Does this answer your question? [Display/Print one column from a DataFrame of Series in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122910/display-print-one-column-from-a-dataframe-of-series-in-pandas)

Comment: `max(df[df['city'] = city]['sales'])`?

Comment: @msanford How does that filter by a specific city?

Comment: `for city in df['city']:`

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop? This is usually not the most computationally efficient way of working on a DataFrame, better to use built in (vectorised) implemnentations instead. It's going to be difficult to help you without you providing an example of your dataset

Comment: Ok, to clarify - 
I have a data frame with Date, city, sales - 
Date                  City Sales
2008-01-01      C1.   10000
2008-01-01      C2    2000
2008-01-02      C1.   13000
2008-01-02      C2    5000

and so on...
I have a function for outliers  - 
def detect_discrete_outliers(data):
    outliers=[]
    threshold=3
    mean = np.mean(data)
    std =np.std(data)
    for i in data:
        z_score= (i - mean)/std 
        if np.abs(z_score) > threshold:
            outliers.append(i)
    return outliers

Comment: Now, I want to use this outlier function to remove outliers from df
detect_discrete_outliers(df['sales'])
df = df[~ df['sales'].isin(detect_discrete_outliers(df['sales']))]

This removes the outliers in sales 

However, I think its not accurate to do that, I need to remove outliers for each city and not overall outliers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748428/looping-through-a-dataframe-to-remove-outliers-calling-function-by-city - I asked the similar question here